# PhoneGap Website Ping

Tags: cordova

Is there a way to ping a website using Phonegap? I am trying to do a test on Phonegap for energy consumption. I have done a connection test but want to ping a site

```
function check_network() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    confirm('Connection type:\n ' + states[networkState]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to run something like node.js + [socket.io](http://www.socket.io) on your server, then you could use that to mimic ping: https://github.com/guille/latency-io

You could also do a `XMLHttpRequest` (or [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)) and calc the time difference between request and response. But that won't be very accurate. I.e.: [How to ping in JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961563/how-to-ping-in-javascript-or-jquery)

You can't really do a real `ping`, the Phonegap API doesn't allow you to do such things out of the box.  You could build a plugin to do such things, but then you have to write that native plugin for every platform (i.e. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-android.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I need to test it out of the box as I am testing it against a android app regarding power consumption...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I don't really see the connection between doing a ping and energy consumption (of the phone?).

Comment: Oh I am running an test on CPU, Wifi, 3g, LCD,GPS with in an application call AppScope. But I want ot see if there is a difference in the amount of power consumed between a basic android app and phonegap

Comment: So the ping is just to utilise the wifi as part of the overall test

Comment: So you just want to check if the wifi is connected (to the internet)? You can use one of the first to methods I've written in the answer. You can't do stuff like a network ping as far as I know. If you want to compare with a native app, you should use the same methods (websockets/http req) there.